# Prevent holding enter key in an input field

Tags: javascript

I wrote an application that ask users questions and the user have to type the answer in a single input field, the answer is usually just one word, if the answer is true the user get positive point.
When the user press the enter key, no harm done. But if the user hold the enter key my application don't work properly. There is no need to use the enter anyway. I want to prevent the enter key completely.
I searched and used this code.

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

but my application still get mixed up if the user hold the enter key.
How to prevent the enter key completely.

ps. I need pure java script. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: post the script what you have tried so far?

Comment: You already have the answer, but if it doesn't work, or something else makes it not work, you need to show your complete code.

Comment: Here is my code. `function imeddiate(e){
if (event.keyCode == 13) {return false;}
var properWord = document.getElementById("properWord").innerHTML;
var typed = document.getElementById("inputSpelling").value;
if(typed.toUpperCase()===properWord.toUpperCase()){
placeAdderProgress();
document.getElementById("inputSpelling").disabled;
document.getElementById("inputSpelling").style.background = "#9c3";
document.getElementById("inputSpelling").style.color = "#fff";
audio(); clearInterval(timerSpelling); clearInterval(timer); addScore(); window.setTimeout(function () {Dynamic()}, 600);}
}`

Comment: Well the imeddiate function, will check every letter user typed and see if the answer is correct or not.

Comment: I figure our what the problem is. The problem is with interval, If an interval start with the Enter key, and before the interval finishes the user hit the Enter key again, everything mixed up. does anyone have any idea how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to handle only allowing a single press and not a hold down here  you can, if not just disable the key 13 on document keydown

```
document.onkeydown = handleKeyDown;
document.onkeyup = handleKeyUp;
var keysDown = {};

function handleKeyDown(e) {      
  var keycode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : null;      
  if(keycode == 13) {        
   if(keysDown['13'] == null){   
     keysDown['13'] = true;
   }
  }
}

function handleKeyUp(e) {
  var keycode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : null;
  keysDown[keycode]=null;
  // on key up the key is now removed from the list and can be pressed again
}
```

Comment: I actually removed the onkeyup event from my input tag and added a button that the user have to click after he typed the answer. Now I have the same problem If the user hold enter key while he click on the button the progress bar I have in my page go crazy. How can I prevent the enter key completely. not just in the input box.

Comment: could you see this link please: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coolesterman/oy1s7dp9/3/)